# Event logs SideBySide and CAPI2 when moving an .exe

Tags: virus

I downloaded an .exe a family member received in GMail to scan it for viruses. I didn't open it and the ESET scan came out clean, so I send the .exe file to the trash. But my speakers may have given a strange brief sound (hard to tell, noisy environment), so I checked my windows logs and found two events that occurred when I was manipulating the file:

Information, Event 4097, CAPI2:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2" Guid="{5bbca4a8-b209-48dc-a8c7-b23d3e5216fb}" EventSourceName="Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">4097</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-06-23T17:24:14.7469857Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>38444</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="3180" ThreadID="5588" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>PC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>E=premium-server@thawte.com, CN=Thawte Premium Server CA, OU=Certification Services Division, O=Thawte Consulting cc, L=Cape Town, S=Western Cape, C=ZA</Data> 
  <Data>627F8D7827656399D27D7F9044C9FEB3F33EFA9A</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Error, Event 33, SideBySide:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="SideBySide" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49409">33</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-06-23T17:24:19.3605368Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>38445</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1248" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>PC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762"</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>C:\Users\user\Downloads\eFilmLt 1.exe</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

The second event surprised me because I didn't execute the file, and from what I've read that error means that the program tried to execute but couldn't because it lacked a library. So I took it out of the trash and send it to virustotal, again no detections, but I got another log:

```
Error, Event 33, SideBySide:
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="SideBySide" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49409">33</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-06-23T17:31:58.1812315Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>38446</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="1248" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>PC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762"</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-2978178-230262488-2527467160-1001\$RT2JPHW.exe</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I didn't execute the file at any point, so I'm at a loss on why this events occurred. Should I be concerned or are those events harmless? The file in question: https://we.tl/t-wVQnUzcKtT